# Discord.js awaitReaction filter not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a command that changes based on what emoji the user reacts to a message with. I currently have the following code

```
message.channel.send(embed).then(function (m) {
    m.react(mtc).then(() => m.react(''))
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return [mtc, ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id};
    m.awaitReactions(filter, {maxMatches: 1, time: 5000})
        .then(collected => {
            console.log(collected)
            const reaction = collected.first();
            console.log(reaction);
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('Create To-Do Card')
                .setDescription('You selected ' + reaction.emoji.name);
            message.channel.send(embed);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

I dont think the filter is working as expected as if I log `user.id` it returns `undefined` and if I try to log `user` it returns multiple collections rather than just a single user

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing filter to

````
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return user.id === message.author.id};```
````